# Magento 2: Where to change Weight Unit?

Tags: magento2

I'm taking my first steps with Magento2 and it's a bit of a struggle.
I want to change the weight unit (Picture: Gewichtseenheid (in Dutch)) but it's grayed out and on the right there is Use Standard (Gebruik Standaard). But where can I find this standard for weight unit (but also for storename etc)

[image: Weight unit]

Comment: For those like me trying to find where this was & got this link as a Top result on Google: `Stores` -> `Configuration` -> `Pick your Store/Default Config` -> `General` -> `General` -> `Locale Options` -> `Weight Unit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you untick the `Gebruik Standaard` checkbox you can edit the value.

The reason being, you are on the website level (see the drop-down on the left above the side Navi). This way you can configure values separately for websites, stores, and store views.

Main differences:

**Websites**: each website has its unique customer and order base. Websites are ‘parents’ of stores. A website consists of one or more stores.

**Stores**: stores can be used eg: to have 2 exact same content stores using different themes and URLs.

**Store views**: Store Views are mostly used to handle different languages on your website eg: one Store View per language.

Depending on the module, each value in the backend can be set either for the global website level, store-level, or store view level. The `Use Standard` checkbox allows you to use the settings of the parent, so you don't have to configure multiple stores separately with the same settings if you just configure their parent website.

Please see: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/websites-stores-views.html

Comment: Okay but how/where can I change these parent settings so I avoid having to configure multiple stores

Comment: Have a look in Stores > Settings > All Stores to get an overview of your configuration. The drop down above the settings navigation "Winkelzicht" is which level you are on currently and which settings you are configuring. If you only have 1 website, store and store view, the drop down will not be displayed. `Use system value` is the default setting used when installing and preset in the module upon installation.